How to create AppImage of KeePassXC using docker image?
I found the following error message when I build KeePassXC using docker image.
[ INFO ] Testing for AppImage tools...
[ INFO ] Downloading appimagetool...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
100 8605k  100 8605k    0     0  1985k      0  0:00:04  0:00:04 --:--:-- 5381k
[ INFO ] Collecting libs and patching binaries...
fusermount: could not determine username

Cannot mount AppImage, please check your FUSE setup.
You might still be able to extract the contents of this AppImage
if you run it with the --appimage-extract option.
See https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/wiki/FUSE
for more information
open dir error: No such file or directory
[ INFO ] Checking out original branch...
[ INFO ] Leaving source directory...
[ ERROR ] Error occurred!

How to fix this issue?
